# Как перейти с формы на форму, чтобы предыдушая закрылась окончательно?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
private: System::Void pictureBox2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { 
     MyForm1 ^ F2;
     F2=gcnew MyForm1();
     F2->Show();
}
```

Что нужно прописать в коде, чтобы перейдя на указанную форму закрылась действительная?

Указанное ниже у меня не сработало.

```
MyForm->Visible=False;

MyForm->Hide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто прятать текущую форму перед открытием следующей:

```
this->Hide();

MyForm1^ F2;
F2 = gcnew MyForm1();
F2->Show();
```

Однако, есть нюанс. Если `this` - главная форма приложения, то она останется висеть в памяти. И после закрытия второй формы, всё приложение останется висеть в памяти. Подумайте, как этого избежать.

Можно использовать `this->Close();`, но только если это не главная форма. Потому что, если закрыть главную форму, то всё приложение целиком завершит работу, не открыв вторую форму.

Comment: Спасибо, вышло.

Comment: Возращаться к первой форме со второй по такому же принципу? Потому что я написала и заголовочный файл и переход по кнопке как в главной кнопке, а оно предоставляет ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

В продолжение ответа @AlexanderPetrov. Можно в конструкторе передать главную форму, и закрыть ее при закрытие второй формы.

Главная форма:

```
private: System::Void pictureBox2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {     
     MyForm1 ^ F2;
     F2=gcnew MyForm1(this);
     F2->Show();    
}
```

Которую нужно открыть:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ mainform;    

MyForm1(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ frm)
{         
     InitializeComponent();
     mainform = frm;
}    

private: System::Void ButtonCancel_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
     this->Close();
     mainform->Close();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Возращаться к первой форме со второй по такому же принципу? Потому что я написала и заголовочный файл и переход по кнопке как в главной кнопке, а оно предоставляет ошибку.